# How to set the output frequency of external DAC in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ios, itunes, audio

How can I specifically set the output format (e.g., 24 bit 192 kHz) when I connect an external DAC to the iPhone?

In the Mac, you can easily adjust the output format using the Audio MIDI Setup. However, I don't see any such setting in iOS.

DAC: Tempotec Sonata HD Pro connected to the iPhone using a Type C Female to Lightning Male Adaptor.
Purpose: Lossless Audio music from Apple Music

Comment: Does your audio device have an app? I would think that a quick call to their technical support would help you get what you want if there is not an app that would do this for you.

Comment: Looking at the manufacturer's support pages, it looks like there's nothing other than Windows support/drivers.